# Move next Activity after animation is finished in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I am using *RotatingTextWrapper* in android for text animation. It is working well. But I want to move next Activity after animation is finished automatically by giving time interval. I have used Thread for this purpose and placed animation inside of thread function. Unfortunately Animation is not working but after few second second Activity is opened automatically. Please Help me.
**Here is Source Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;
    Timer timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv=findViewById(R.id.txt);

       final Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf");
       final Typeface typeface2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Reckoner_Bold.ttf");

        tv.setTypeface(typeface2);

        timer=new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                RotatingTextWrapper rotatingTextWrapper = (RotatingTextWrapper) findViewById(R.id.custom_switcher);
                rotatingTextWrapper.setSize(30);
                rotatingTextWrapper.setTypeface(typeface2);

                Rotatable rotatable = new Rotatable(Color.parseColor("#af030f"), 3000, "Xafa", "Hazil", "Uzr","Sizni","Juda");
                rotatable.setSize(30);
                rotatable.setTypeface(typeface);
                rotatable.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                rotatable.setAnimationDuration(600);

                Rotatable rotatable2 = new Rotatable(Color.parseColor("#123456"), 3000, "qimoqchimasdim", "Ediku", "So`rayman","Yoqtiraman","ham");
                rotatable2.setSize(30);
                rotatable2.setTypeface(typeface);
                rotatable2.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                rotatable2.setAnimationDuration(600);

                rotatingTextWrapper.setContent("?  ?", rotatable, rotatable2);

                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        },4000);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think is `finish() method` of MainActivity is cause that (App exit).

Comment: No it is not working still

Comment: have you confirmed that the animation works inside a single activity? (base case)

Comment: Yes it is working inside single Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //logic
        }
    }, 4000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the animation in the onResume() stage of the activity lifecycle. According to [Android documentation for Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) onStart() "...makes activity visible to the user..." and onResume() "...app interacts with the user...".

Since you want your animation to be visible to the user, I would place it in onStart() and use the logic of the design to make onResume() handle your animation.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
 @OnCreate()
 // instantiations class member variables
 @OnStart()
 // timer code for animation
 @OnResume()
 Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
 this.startActivity(i);
}
```